# Getting error while calling JNI method

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I implemented two objects in the same JNI library. It worked fine till I implemented two identical methods for both classes. The definition looks like:

Class1:

```
jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_applications_Class1_GetRectangles
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
```

Class2:

```
jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_applications_Class2_GetPoints
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
```

After that my application started crashing on calling any JNI method from the library. I understand that there is a conflict. Is there any recipe to keep these methods and get it working?

Logcat dump from the point of crash does not say much:

```
04-16 22:07:12.573 I/JNI NativePointDetector( 7171): Calling Process method

04-16 22:07:12.664 W/fb4a(:<default>):QuickExperimentControllerImpl( 7248): Exposure of experiment com.facebook.push.mqtt.service.MqttServiceProcessSelection@23144964 occurred when no user was logged in

04-16 22:07:12.674 W/CameraService(  185): Disconnecting camera client 0xb320c090 since the binder for it died (this pid 185)

04-16 22:07:12.677 I/WindowState(  530): WIN DEATH: Window{1ecf2e2e u0 com.applications.MyApp/com.applications.MyApp.MainActivity}

04-16 22:07:12.677 W/WindowManager(  530): Force-removing child win Window{3283efbd u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{1ecf2e2e u0 com.applications.MyApp/com.applications.MyApp.MainActivity}

04-16 22:07:12.680 E/qdhwcomposer(  179): Failed to send data over socket: Bad file number

04-16 22:07:12.687 W/WindowManager(  530): Failed looking up window

04-16 22:07:12.687 W/WindowManager(  530): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@2ef387eb does not exist

04-16 22:07:12.687 W/WindowManager(  530):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8412)

04-16 22:07:12.687 W/WindowManager(  530):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8403)

04-16 22:07:12.687 W/WindowManager(  530):  at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1113)

04-16 22:07:12.687 W/WindowManager(  530):  at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:551)

04-16 22:07:12.687 I/WindowState(  530): WIN DEATH: null
```

Comment: Post your LogCat outputs

Comment: Logcat does not provide much information. I published it between method call and termination.

Comment: Your posted error doesn't seem to have anything directly to do with your jni code - by appearances it isn't even coming from your process.  It's possible though that these messages follow from an *earlier* failure of your code which is not included in the log excerpt you posted.

Comment: You can't seriously expect to get help with your code when you don't post any code. I would guess you got a JNI error in one of those methods and didn't detect it.

Comment: @EJP - I think the poster is proposing that the very idea of having two similar methods might be the problem, and so has provided the code that illustrates that they do.  That isn't the source of the problem here, but it's not a wild theory - there are other environments where only the first n characters of a method name matter.

Comment: @ChrisStratton If so he's wrong, and it is still perfectly in order to ask for the code.

Comment: @AlexanderZorin "I understand that there is a conflict." What conflict?

Comment: @EJP NativePointDetector is a method of Class2, which worked before I added new methods, described in my question. Once I added these two methods, I started getting the error, even these methods are not called. I will post the code later.It looks like functions pointer table is spoiled.